# Significant-Location change notification in iPod

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-location

My application uses location service in background. To reduce the battery drainage, i found that it is better to register for significant-location change notification. It says to get this notification device need cell radio. Now my doubt is that whether i can get significant location change notification in iPod....I searched a lot but couldn't get an exact answer..any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: The best thing i say to test it by urself..

Comment: thanks for your time...how can i test it? significant location change work based on the network cell signal strength and all..iPod does not have capabilities for getting network signal other than Wi-Fi....I am eager to know whether apple has any other method to handle this( monitoring network signal strength)...any idea?

Comment: i tried in iPhone without cellular n/w only for 10-20 mtrs, but didn't find any changes in co-ordinates.. latr i left for my client/testers to go test it.. u can test in around 100-200 mtrs distance with different accuracy settings, you can get some results..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As significant Location Change Monitoring needs radio signals and iPod is not capable of having that signal so it wont work on iPod (as per my knowledge).

But you can check from this method to know whether your device is capable of this service or not

[`+ (BOOL)significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable)

Comment: thanks a lot ....i was thinking same as you, but "checkSignificantLocationMonitoringAvailabe" method returns true for my 5th (MD720LL) generation iPod and false for  4th(MC540ZP) generation iPod....